# Use of undefined constant category_id - assumed 'category_id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I get the error above when I am trying to pass a foreign key to main table using a hidden field in the form. This is the line I added:
`<input type="hidden" value="{{ category_id }}">`

I also tried to do:
`<input type="hidden" value="{{ $assortments->category_id }}">` since `category_id` is a foreign key of that table. Does anybody know how I can solve this problem?

I already tried looking in the Laravel documentation and I read other StackOverflow questions about this subject but their answers did not help me out.

`category_id` is a column in the `assortments` table. I am trying to pass that id. It is not a variable.`category_id` is a foreign key.

I also wrote it like this:
`<input type="hidden" value="{{ $category_id }}">`

Which gives the following error:

`Undefined variable: category_id`

Comment: you're missing a $ sign in `{{ category_id }}` that's the error, if the variable is defined, it will work, if not, you need to add more details to your question.

Comment: `category_id` is a column in the `assortments` table. It is not a variable. I want to pass that id in the form

Comment: Please check the edit @N69S

Comment: you still need to add more details regarding how you are sending the assortment data to the view/blade